# Using XMLReader with Google App Engine Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, xmlreader

I have a 30MB XML file which I'd like to process using Google App Engine (PHP). Because the file is so big, the suggested storage is Google Cloud Storage, so I've placed it there. Because of memory constraints, I can't parse the whole file at once, but it contains 5000 nodes which are all very reasonably-sized, so I'm trying to use XML Reader to pull in one node at a time.

The process works perfectly locally, but the issue I'm having is that **XMLReader keeps failing to read from my cloud storage with the message "unable to open source data"**.

Here's an example of my code:

```
$path = "gs://my_bucket/my_file.xml";
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
$public_url = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl($path, true);

$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open( $path ); // fails
$reader->open( $public_url ); // fails
```

Both the "internal" and the public URL fail with the same error:

> XMLReader::open(): Unable to open source data in /[gaepath]/myapp.php on line X

Having read around, there are suggestions about permissions, but the file is not restricted and the following *does* work:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($path); // $xml contains the file contents as a string
```

Two solutions would help me:

1. Some way to have XMLReader open a Google Cloud Storage URL
2. Some way to pass a string to XMLReader, which does not appear to be possible (and writing a temporary local file also appears to be forbidden on GAE)

Comment: Are you certain that XMLReader can read from a stream that is not a local file?

Comment: @StuartLangley The (not particularly verbose) docs suggest so (http://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.open.php) and it seems to work with a URL locally...

Comment: I looked at the code and it seems to suggest it only works with local files.... https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/xmlreader/php_xmlreader.c#L241

Comment: have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Looks like we need to manually enable a "[Disabled Function](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Disabled_functions)" by creating a php.ini file in the root of our app.

php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "libxml_disable_entity_loader"
```

Then, in the code, we need to enable the entity loader before loading the file:

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$xml = new XMLReader();
$res = $xml->open($file);
```